# How can div hide bydefault onload event

Tags: c#, javascript, xml, xslt

I have a dropdown list which by default shows 'select' option on page load.  Below that is a `DataGrid` which contains some data. How do I hide the data in the div when the dropdown has 'select' selected? When I change the option to something other than 'select', I would like it to show the data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that when the page loads, the dropdown is without selection (so 'select' is showing), just hide your DataGrid with css by default by adding something like this to your css file(s):

```
#myDataGrid{
   display: none;
}
```

and when the selection changes, show it (using jQuery for example):

```
jQuery('#mySelect').change(function(){
    //(this assumes that your select option has value 'select')
    if(jQuery("#mySelect").val() == 'select'){
        jQuery('#myDataGrid').hide();
    }else{
        jQuery('#myDataGrid').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: You can check in the change handler whether the selected option was the 'select' option, and in that case hide it again. I'll update my example